# Safari showing popups all the time

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, tooltips, safari

As per the image, Safari has been showing the roll-over popups all the time on all Stack Exchange sites.
I've tried disabling all ad blockers but to no avail.
I'm on MacOS 11.2.3, using Safari 14.0.3.

Edit: A stopgap solution was to add `.s-popover.s-popover__tooltip` to the CSS Hide Elements list in 1Blocker.
The downside is that this completely removes the tooltips so that they can't be seen even when hovering over the buttons.

[image]

Comment: MSO cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404127/tooltips-are-persistently-visible-on-safari  / cc @Glorfindel

Comment: @Thomas do you happen to have Grammarly, 1Password, or Readcube Papers installed on your Safari?

Comment: I do indeed have ReadCube Papers installed.

Comment: Disabling ReadCube Papers extension resolved this problem

Answer (score 5):

In my case, disabling ReadCube Papers extension resolved this problem.